# Make CSS popup always stay on top of it's parent

Tags: html, css

I have a two divs.

One with position relative, and another one with position absolute.

They act somehow as a popup button.

Is there any way of forcing the `div` with `position: absolute` to always stay on top of it's parent, no matter what height it has?

On top i mean "standing on top of it", not `z-index` property

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Rhb3M/)

```
<div style="position: relative; border: 1px solid #000; padding: 2px;">
    <span>Popup container</span>
    <div style="position: absolute;">
        <div style="height: 100px; background-color: #f0f0f0; top: 0;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Has `popupParent` fixed height?

Comment: Yes, it has fixed height

Comment: Found a solution: `popup: bottom: 0; margin-bottom: 20px;`

Answer (score 1):

Sizes are calculated based on the container not itself

So you need to give it a

```
bottom:100%;
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/Rhb3M/4/

Answer (score 0):

If your `popupParent` has fixed height (for example `100px`) then you can use `bottom`:

```
bottom: 100px;
```

Check updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Rhb3M/2/

Also remember about another values which you should add (paddings, margins, borders)

In Your case it will `105px` (`100px height + border + 2*padding`)